# What is the best way to send Teams Message to a Channel

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

What is the best way to send Teams Message to a Channel. I tried using web hook I was successful, but it seems like this method does not allow access to channels or tags to only send a message to a small subgroup in the larger group.

I used client.UploadString to post to the web hook

I am not familiar with graph

If anyone has any good examples, I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

If you want to send proactive messages using Teams bot, you can refer this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet

You can also send proactive installation messages in 1:1:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/proactive-bots-and-messages/graph-proactive-bots-and-messages?tabs=dotnet

You can also use Graph API to send chatMessage in a channel or a chat:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Note: Sample links are present in the documentation.

Comment: These are good to know but do not help me because my company is global company , I would need permission to Graph to allow programmatic changes to Teams. I found a solution using incoming webbook , it allows to post message to the main teams group and individual channels

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using incoming webbook , it allows to post message to the main teams group and individual channels

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).